# If I buy Minecraft on PS4, will I get a Premium license for the PC version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

If i buy the PS4 edition of Minecraft and sign in with my Mojang account, will I also be granted a premium license for the PC edition of the game?

Comment: If I buy GTA5 on Xbox will I get the pc version for free?

Answer (score 1):

No that's not how it works, you would have to buy it on PC as well

Comment: Ok but will i have a premium license on my account if i buy the PS4 edition?

Comment: @PS4G4MER No you will not